# android soft keyboard is not visible when input type set to number for edittext

Tags: java, android

Here is my **XML** code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amtEdt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="0.00"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="7"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/remarks"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/lightgrey" />
```

I have two edittext one is for entering number another is for entering string.The issue is when open the activity soft keyboard is opening for string edittext.For number input edittext keyboard is not opening.Cursor focus is focusing for second editext not for first edittext

Comment: Test case : Try to set `android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"` width to your `amtEdt`

Comment: its not working for me

Answer (score -1):

might be some copy problem but when i removed your property inputType="number" and again applied from suggestions it worked , here is the editText workd for

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/amtEdt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="0.00"
    android:maxLength="7"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"/>
```